# Remote Camera Communication

Tags: java, android, client-server, arduino, rc

I am looking to make a remote control car with a camera which can be controlled via an Android Phone. This requires a lot of things, but the only thing i am confused about is how to communicate the camera's image with the phone. I can handle the code and stuff and i know networking well, and i've done server-client many many times, but what i really need is to know how i can hook up a camera to some sort of WiFi enabled motherboard on the RC Car. The RC Car should be able to communicate over WiFi and i also want a motherboard which would let the WiFi data coming in from the client (Android phone) control the motor speeds and stuff. Where do i start? I'm really confused on how data being sent over a socket to my RC Car will control the motors, and also how camera data from the car will be sent to the phone.

Basically, I need a way to have control over motors and also have a way for the car to send me video. How do i do this?

Comment: What thoughts/ideas have you had so far about the protocol?  You know that without that, you have nothing, right?

Comment: Im thinking using the ADK. Although i am totally lost on where to start, but ive been in the same place before, ill figure it out if invest in it, but I think using an Arduino device with WiFi enabled module, programmed in C++ or something wud be good enough to read/write to sockets and control electrical signals. But i have to start from 0 since i have little experience with electrical boards and what wire goes in what pin and stuff. O.O

Comment: Since you seem to be struggling with the electronics stuff, it would be better to ask this question on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stream the cameras input over the network. In order to achieve this you could use the Gstremer in both car-(streaming server) android phone ( client ). With a gstremer you will set the camera as your input stream and rtsp sink as a renderer so you client ( iphone app ) will be able to connect to the live streaming server on your car.